# Why can't I get the childNodes of this div element properly?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get all the children of a div element (code below) in order to create a mechanism that unchecks parent checkboxes when none of the children are checked. All the children are in the same div but when I use div.childNodes[0], for example I get an Object Text element instead of a Div element.

The html code:

```
<div id="div_chk_ctl_adaugare" style="width: 100%; border: 0; padding: 0; background-color: white;">
            <div style="width: 99.5%-10px; border: 0; padding-left: 10px; background-color: white;">
                <input class="chck_nivel2_adaugare" id="chk_ctl_adaugare_conturi" name="chk_ctl_adaugare_conturi" type="checkbox" onChange="check_conturi_actiuni(\'adaugare\');" /><label for="pm_conturi_adaugare"><img id="pm_conturi_adaugare" name="plus" src="crm/imagini/plus-10.png" cursor="pointer"></img> Conturi </label>
            </div> 
                <div id="div_dir_conturi_adaugare" style="width: 100%; border: 0; padding: 0; background-color: white;">
                    '.$div_dir_conturi.'
                </div>
            <div style="width: 99.5%-10px; border: 0; padding-left: 10px; background-color: white;">
                <input class="chck_nivel2_adaugare" id="chk_ctl_adaugare_contacte" name="chk_ctl_adaugare_contacte" type="checkbox" onChange="check_contacte_actiuni(\'adaugare\');" /><label for="pm_contacte_adaugare"><img id="pm_contacte_adaugare" name="plus" src="crm/imagini/plus-10.png" cursor="pointer"></img> Contacte </label>
            </div> 
                <div id="div_dir_contacte_adaugare" style="width: 100%; border: 0; padding: 0; background-color: white;">
                    '.$div_dir_contacte.'
                </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var div_col = document.getElementById("div_chk_ctl_"+tip);
//alert(div_col.childNodes[0].data);
var uncheck_tate = 1;
for(var j = 0; j<div_col.childNodes.length; j+=2) {
    alert(div_col.childNodes[j]);
    if(div_col.childNodes[j].childNodes[0].checked == true) {
        uncheck_tate = 0        
    }
}

if(uncheck_tate == 1)
    document.getElementById("chk_ctl_"+tip).checked = false;
else
    document.getElementById("chk_ctl_"+tip).checked = true;
```

The uncommented alert prints [object Text]. 
Is there something about childNodes that I'm missing here? could I use anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having such text nodes, don't have any space between the elements: (that space is the text nodes you see)

```
<div id="div_chk_ctl_adaugare" style="width: 100%; border: 0; padding: 0; background-color: white;"><div style="width: 99.5%-10px; border: 0; padding-left: 10px; background-color: white;"><input class="chck_nivel2_adaugare" id="chk_ctl_adaugare_conturi" name="chk_ctl_adaugare_conturi" type="checkbox" onChange="check_conturi_actiuni(\'adaugare\');" /><label for="pm_conturi_adaugare"><img id="pm_conturi_adaugare" name="plus" src="crm/imagini/plus-10.png" cursor="pointer"></img> Conturi </label></div>.....
```

If you prefer to have readable HTML, just check the node type:

```
if (div_col.childNodes[j].nodeType != 3) {
    //not text node, OK to go...
}
```

Comment: @Bogdan The browser is ignoring the white spaces when rendering the HTML for display. Behind the scenes, in the infamous "DOM tree" those white spaces are not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the inputs that are descendants of an element, not just the direct children, use *getElementsByTagName*:

```
var div_col = document.getElementById("div_chk_ctl_"+tip);
var inputs = div_col.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  // do stuff with inputs[i]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really want only the direct children. It's a HUGE tiered tree of check lists. What I posted here is just 2 elements for the sake of the example.

Comment: It would really help if you removed all the superfluous markup and posted just the structure you are tying to deal with.